# How to change desktop environments in linux mint that have to be built from source

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have moved from Slackware to Linux Mint after over 20 years of using Slackware, mostly because of the package managers. Now I am finding that Mint has no easy way of changing desktop environments that are not a part of the software repositories. In particular I want to setup Enlightenment DR-16 as my desktop, which has to be built from source. In order to change desktops in Slackware all one has to do is open up .xinitrc and place the startup file name in and save and type startx and the DE you want starts right up. This doesn't work in Mint. SO what do I have to change in Mint to get E-16 to come up? I have searched this out on the web and all I have found is how to change desktop environments with installing software from the repositories.

Comment: Which DE did you select when you installed Mint (some play better with others)?  Is there a reason why you want to install E-16 rather than the current version?  According to this link, adding it should be pretty trivial (no building from source, you're not in Slackware anymore): http://www.noobslab.com/2015/12/install-enlightenment-e20-desktop-in.html or http://www.2daygeek.com/install-enlightenment-desktop-on-ubuntu-mint/#

Comment: E20 is too unstable for one thing, E16 is very stable and has a very small footprint, I just like it more than any other DE. I am using Cinnamon right now and E16 won't interfere with it because E16 will use the ubuntu programs and file managers.

Comment: It looks like E17 is available in the Mint package manager (since ~1 yr ago): https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/e17.  E16 may be in there, also.

Comment: Looks like E16 was available in Mint ~5 yrs ago: https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/e16.  Is this still even supported?

Comment: Yes it is still supported

Comment: You triggered my interest.  A little Googling and I learned where you're coming from with E16. You're probably way ahead of me, but just in case, I'll pass this on.  Bodhi forked E17 to [Moksha](http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-install-bodhi-linux-s-moksha-desktop-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-and-linux-mint-17-2-491737.shtml). Don't know how the footprint and stability compare to E16, but it's reportedly much more stable than E17, and optimized while retaining the added E17 features. Also, it's ready to use for Mint. So it isn't what you asked, but I'll pass it on in case you want to check it out.

Comment: Well instead of someone answering the question, everyone has focused on E-16 which is not the question. The question is, "how do I change DEs  in Linux Mint? What config files do I have to edit to get Mint Linux to boot up with my preferred DE?

Comment: You're right.  Maybe my comments and your last one will get the distractions out of people's systems and focus on the issue.  :-)  I suspect that the lack of response is because nobody else has pursued this in recent times.  Do you have the source files, so the question is just how to configure what you have (if so, what is your starting point--actual source files you need to compile vs. a package from another distro, etc.), or do you also need to locate E16 in some form and implementation will depend on what's available?  Might be worth editing in that clarification to bump the question.

Comment: Do you have X11 installed?

Answer (score 0):

Your value -might- be found here:

/etc/X11/default-display-manager

This is assuming, of course, that you don't care for a display manager like gdm or kdm to be handling the desktop environment choices for you.

That said if you've been using slackware for 20 odd years and moved to mint, I have a feeling that since you asked this back in September that you probably got frustrated with the experience and moved on to something more clement to your expectations of experience. Let us know how it went :)

Comment: Are you telling me that all I have to do is edit and comment out /usr/sbin/mdm and I can kill the display manager and it will boot into a CLI as I have normally done and then just put the window manager or DE in .xinitrc and do startx?

Comment: Nah, to do that sounds a little more complicated - from some googling on 'boot mint into cli' - Edit your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file and add the word "text" after the words "quiet splash" under the section that starts with ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###.  Be sure to use sudo to edit the file (don't use the " marks).

Comment: But give it a shot anyways maybe it'll do that